# How to localize (translate) exception message in Firebird/Interbase?

Tags: exception, localization, firebird, translate, interbase

is there any chance to translate Interbase/Firebird exception messages ? For eg. I have Exception

> TOO_MANY_CONNECTS 'There are to many connect to database, please try again later.'

And now clients from other country (for eg. Russia) want to see exception message in their native lang.
I know that FireBird 2.1 allow to put custom exception message (and it solves my problem), but InterBase 7.5 don't.

Thanks.

Comment: One option is to translate it on the application side, by taking the English message as the resource key to look up to the translated variant.

Comment: I was afraid of that, so Thank you for answer :)

Comment: That is one of the reasons I posted as a comment instead of an answer. I hope you (or some one else) finds a better way.

Comment: Not sure if this will help you but theoretically in PSQL you can override the exception's default message. Check this [link](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd15-psql-exception.html) in the Firebird docs.

Comment: @GuillemVicens: Yes i know it. But problem is that Interbae 7.5 doesn't have this function.

Comment: If you translate it yourself on the application side, as suggested, you can then also display the official IB error message. You don't have to translate every message, especially if you are writing for the end user, who may not understand all messages even if translated.